# Using AWS Sagemaker (Ground Truth) for Labeling Jobs + Rekognition. How best to approach my project?

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, image-segmentation, sagemaker

I'm new to ML so bear with me. I want to create an object detection model that can detect anything from flags (e.g. Israel flag) to symbols (e.g. yin-yang sign) to a giving setting (e.g. war).

I am using AWS Rekognition already, but there's a number of objects Rekognition does not detect. That lead me to Sagemaker Ground Truth and creating labeling jobs using Mechanical Turk.

I scraped several hundred images from Google for each category (i.e. did a google image search for that image and pulled each image) and put them in their respective folder (e.g. Israel flag, Palestine flag). For each image scraped:

1. It may not even contain the actual object.
2. The entire image may just be a picture of the object (e.g. Israel flag).
3. The image may contain the object as well as other objects (e.g. Israel flag and the U.S. flag)

When I set up my labeling job:

1. Should I curate the scraped images before putting them in an s3 bucket? For situation 1 above, many of the google images (especially for lesser well known objects) have nothing to do with the actual label (i.e. may show a picture of a building instead of an Israeli flag). Or just create another label called "N/A"?
2. Should I set it up as a Bounding box task? For situation 2 above, in that case the mechanical turk would just draw a boundary box around the entire image.
3. I currently have each image in its own folder. When I set up the labeling job, the labels are just for that object (i.e. the Israel Flag labeling job is all images of the Israel flag and the label is just "Israel flag"). Instead of setting it up like that, my thought is just putting all the flag images in one folder and then having multiple labels (e.g. Israel flag, Palestine flag, Afghanistan flag, etc.) Like in situation 3, if there are multiple flags in a single image, the mechanical turk can label all instances of that object rather than not at all. The only problem here is I am capped at 50 labels and there are 200+ countries.

Am I thinking about this the right way? Appreciate any help/feedback.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.